# Question about computing variation of some functions

Tags: real-analysis, bounded-variation

It is relatively standard to prove $f\in BV([a,b])$ iff $f$ can be written as a difference of two monotone increasing functions.

**QUESTION**: I have two functions, and I am trying to compute the total variation *and* actually find the explicit monotone functions.

My first function is $f:[-10,10]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=|x+1|-2|x-2|$
My second function is: $g:[-4\pi, 2\pi]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $g(x)=sin(x)+cos(x)$.

I am using the Jordan decomposition for functions so I want to write $f$ as 
$f=f^{+}-f^{-}$. I also know the variation $V(f)=f^{+}(b)-f^{+}(b)+f^{-}(b)-f^{-}(a)$

Note $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $x^{+}=max\{0,x\}$ and $x^{-}=-min\{x,0\}$.

let $P(f)=\{x_0=-10<x_1<...<x_{n-1}<x_n=10\}$ be a partition for $f$. 
let $P(g)=\{x_0=-4\pi< x_1<...<x_{n-1}<x_n={2\pi}\}$ be a partition for $g$

Define $S_{P}(f)^{+}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}[f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})]^{+}$ (positive terms of the function $f$)

and $S_{P}(f)^{-}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}[f(x_i)-f(x_{i-1})]^{-}$  (negative terms of the function)

similarly, we let the positive and negative variation of the function be defined as

$V(f)^{+}=sup\{S_P\}^{+}$, $V(f)^{-}=sup\{S_P\}^{-}$ respectively and the total variation is $V(f)=V(f)^{+}+V(f)^{-}$.

I have an issue going from these definitions to the explicit computations I need. I know for $g$ I could argue it's Lipschitz (since derivative is bounded), hence absolutely continuous, hence BV, but I want to use the definition directly. For $f$, I am stuck.

Finally, when you compute the variation of a function, can we use finite partitions (such as $n=4$), or do we need to compute the variation for an infinite sum? It seems that proving a function is *NOT* of bounded variation always involves considering an infinite sum for the partition.

Comment: This is all very complicated. How about drawing the graphs and going from there? Or as you are dealing with a piecewise differentiable function, just take your first increasing function to be $x\mapsto Mx$ where $M$ is an upper bound for the derivative of your function.

Answer (score 1):

Your functions $f$ and $g$ here are quite tame. Break up your interval
$[a,b]$ into finitely many intervals $[a_0,a_1]$, $[a_1,a_2]\ldots,[a_{n-1},a_n]$
on which $f$ is monotone. Then the total variation of $f$ on each $[a_{j-1},a_j]$
is $|f(a_j)-f(a_{j-1})|$ and the total variation of $f$ is
$\sum_{j=1}^n|f(a_j)-f(a_{j-1})|$.

Comment: for $f$ take $n=20$ for our partition of $[-10,10]$? We want $f$ to be monotone increasing right? As an alternative solution, I suppose I could use the theorem $V(f)=\int_{a}^{b}|f'|dx$ (similarly for $g$), I am unsure if this is valid for the non-differentiable points of $f$.

Comment: @Kernel_Dirichlet $20$ is a number, not a partition. I advocate drawing the graphs of these functions, and looking at them.

Comment: what I meant was to partition the interval into $n=20$ pieces, starting from $x_0=-10<x_1<...<x_{n-1}<x_n=10$ and sum the variation of each of these intervals. I worked out some simpler examples of $C^1([-10,10])$ functions and compared it to the integral criteria $V(f)=\int_{a}^{b}|f'|dx$ and got matching answers. I am wondering if $n=20$ was arbitrary, and we could replace $20$ with any finite number. This would lead to a regular partition with each sub-interval of length $h=\frac{b-a}{n}$ (in our case $h=\frac{20}{n}$)

Comment: @Kernel_Dirichlet $20$ is a **lot** of intervals; you are still over-complicating. Please draw the graphs of these functions and divide up the interval appropriately. By the way, bringing integrals in here is another unnecessary complication.

Comment: Also for $g$ the integral I would argue is a simplification because $g\in C^1([-10,10])$ and we can compute the variation through simply evaluating $\int_{a}^{b}|g'|dx$ which is not too complicated. Although for $f$ we can't use the theorem because $g$ is not differentiable at each point so the theorem doesn't apply.